# How to find path of user's home directory in PHP Cli on linux?

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu, home-directory

I am trying to write an script to check a particular directory exits or not on current logged in user's home directory via PHP.

when on terminal I use

```
    cd ~
    pwd
```

It shows `/home/ramratan`.

But when I tried via PHP the same thing like below

```
    chdir("~");
    PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) 
    in php shell code on line 1
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
    PHP   2. chdir() php shell code:1
```

I also tried below

```
 chdir("/home");
 echo shell_exec("pwd");
```

It displays `/home` not `/home/ramratan`, if someone help me what should I do in `chdir("/home")` so that it returns `/home/ramratan`.

I have also tried below but no success

```
 chdir("/home/".shell_exec("whoami"));
 PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) 
 in php shell code on line 1
 PHP Stack trace:
 PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
 PHP   2. chdir() php shell code:1
```

Comment: How do you mean "the current logged in user"? `whoami` will return as which user apache is running as, not the user you have logged in on your site.

Comment: @DarkBee, echo shell_exec("whoami"); is returning ramratan not nginx user.

Comment: @DarkBee is correct.  My doubt is are you making directory name same as the logged in user name ? in that case insted of shell_exec("whoami"), you can do chdir("/home/".$loggedinUserName);

Comment: php -a
Interactive shell

php > $logedin = shell_exec("whoami");
php > echo $logedin;
ramratan
php > $path =  "/home/".$logedin;
php > echo $path;
/home/ramratan
php > echo shell_exec("pwd");
/home/ramratan/knexus-codebase
php > chdir($path);
PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. chdir() php shell code:1
php > echo shell_exec("pwd");
/home/ramratan/knexus-codebase
php > echo $path;
/home/ramratan

Comment: I finally found solution, there was a new line, I used trim for  whoami path and it works! chdir("/home/".trim(shell_exec("whoami"))); echo shell_exec("pwd");
/home/ramratan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the current username by using `whomai` as you already wrote. Use that name to find the line corresponding to that user in `/etc/passwd`. From that line `cut` out the home dir information:

```
$currentUserHomeDir = exec('grep `whoami` /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f6');
```

Comment: This is extended solution, echo prints /home/ramratan without sudo -s and also prints /root with sudo -s

Answer (score 1):

The `CLI` version of `PHP` puts the environment variables in `$_SERVER[]`. The home directory of the current user can be found in `$_SERVER['HOME']`. There is no need to change any directory or run any external command.

Tested it on OSX and Ubuntu but I am confident it works on any Linux distribution. Cannot tell anything about Windows at the moment.

Comment: this is simple solution, echo prints `/home/ramratan`  without sudo -s and also prints `/home/ramratan` with sudo -s